# Javascript regex seems to add backslash to replacement

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a `textearea` called `note_text`, a `div` called `note_preview` and this function:

```
function fence_math(text) {
    return text
        .replace(new RegExp('\\\((.*?)\\\)', 'g'), '`memviv-math $1`')
        .replace(new RegExp('\\\[(.*?)\\\]', 'g'), '`memviv-equation $1`');
}
```

If I run this:

```
note_preview.innerHTML = fence_math(note_text.value);
```

When `note_text` contains

```
\(a *b* c\)
```

I get

```
<div id="note_preview">\`memviv-math a *b* c\`</div>
```

Why are there backslashes before the accents ? I would have expected:

```
<div id="note_preview">`memviv-math a *b* c`</div>
```

What can I do to get the proper result ?

Comment: Maybe because you are serializing a string and you cannot begin another string within a string?

Comment: Could you help me fix it ? I don’t see why the accent is not considered as a regular character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get value from the input it escaping special characters `/` in your case that's why your `note_text.value` is `"\\(a *b* c\\)"`. Try to add extra backslashes to escape to your RegExp functions

```
.replace(new RegExp('\\\\((.*?)\\\\)', 'g'), '`memviv-math $1`')
.replace(new RegExp('\\\\[(.*?)\\\\]', 'g'), '`memviv-equation $1`');
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot that Javascript escaped characters in strings. '\\\\\\((.*?)\\\\\\)' solved my problem.

Comment: No problem. You could mark that answer as accepted if it helped)

Comment: No need for another answer, it is already [172nd post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/17863066?lq=1) on the same topic. Please consider removing it.